# Somewhere between jQuery and Django, my JSON data gets an extra [] and form validation fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

I have a Django model with a `ManyToMany` field called `images`, and a simple `ModelForm` for that model.

I'm trying to post data using jQuery and a very basic `UpdateView`.

### The model's field

```
images = models.ManyToManyField(
    RawImage,
    null = True,
)
```

### The form

```
class PublicDataPoolForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_css_class = 'error'

    class Meta:
        model = PublicDataPool
```

### The UpdateView

```
class PublicDataPoolAddDataView(AjaxableResponseMixin, UpdateView):
    model = PublicDataPool
    form_class = PublicDataPool_ImagesForm

    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: user_has_active_subscription(u)))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PublicDataPoolAddDataView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

### The jQuery posting the data

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/rawdata/publicdatapools/' + pk + '/add-data/',
    data: {images: [1, 2]}
});
```

I get a `ValidationError` because the field `images` is required. If I print my `request.POST` in my `UpdateView`, I get this:

```
<QueryDict: {u'images[]': [u'1', u'2']}>
```

I believe the problem is with those `[]`, because I've checked with another form that gets posted in a more traditional way, and the `request.POST` doesn't have those `[]` in the field name.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to set `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` on page load so that jquery doesn't append the `[]` to the key.

Source:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-post-1-4-1-is-appending-to-vars-when-posting-from-array-within-array#14737000000691277